# Set cookies when downloading files with Salt

Tags: cookies, salt-stack

Is there a way to set cookie values for files downloaded by HTTP on file.managed or archive.extracted. Something along the lines of

```
my-archive:
  archive.extracted:
    - name: /opt/
    - archive_format: tar  
    - tar_options: z
    - source: http://myserver/my-archive.tar.gz
    - source_cookies:
      - cookie1: value1
      - cookie2: value2
```

My concrete use case is downloading jdk from oracle which requires a cookie accepting the license to be downloaded?

Is there anyway to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be an awesome option to have, but it's not available yet. I've seen this done, though.  It's kind of hackish, but should work.

```html
install-java:                                                                   
  cmd.run:                                                                      
    - name: |                                                                   
        cd /tmp                                                                 
        mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm                                                   
        wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u40-b26/server-jre-8u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
        tar xzf server-jre-8u40-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm                
        update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java" 1
        update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java        
    - cwd: /tmp                                                                 
    - shell: /bin/bash                                                          
    - timeout: 300                                                              
    - reload_modules: true                                                      
    - unless: test -x /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_40
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this on this level unfortunately.

Please note that for the particular use case you mentioned (downloading oracle java) there is a formula available: https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/sun-java-formula

You can download/install the UnlimitedJCEPolicy files with too.

Answer (score 0):

No, the archive module does not have any such functionality. Try rewriting the state to use cmd.run instead - this way you can pass whatever parameters you need to the download command.